handling delete request in next config
i am working on a next app route project. there is a DELETE API that i need to call. but the DELETE API did'nt returns a json.so, the next project gets error.
my next API config is below:
import { handleError } from "./errors";

type fetcherProps = {
  url: string;
  method: "GET" | "POST" | "PUT" | "DELETE";
  data?: any;
  options?: FetcherOptions;
  toast?: boolean;
  hasToken?: null | string | boolean;
};

interface FetcherOptions extends Omit<RequestInit, "body"> {
  headers?: Record<string, string>;
}
const responseHandler = (err: any) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.details?.[0]?.message) {
      return err.details[0].message;
    } else if (err.message) {
      return err.message;
    }
  }
};
export const REACT_BASE_ROUTE = "https://example.com/fa/";
export const BASE_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL;
export const BASE_URL_SSR = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL_SSR;

export const ConfigApi = async ({
  url,
  method = "GET",
  data = null,
  options = {},
  toast = false,
  hasToken = null,
}: fetcherProps) => {
  try {
    const config: RequestInit = {
      method,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        authorization: hasToken ? `Bearer ` + hasToken : "",
        ...options.headers,
      },
      ...options,
    };

    if (data && (method === "POST" || method === "PUT")) {
      config.body = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    const response = await fetch(
      (options.next ? BASE_URL_SSR : BASE_URL) + url,
      config
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorResponse = await response.json();
      if (toast) {
        handleError(response.status, responseHandler(errorResponse));
      }
      return null;
    }

   return response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};

I am using fetch in the project.
I don't know were is the problem?! my config or back-end API!

You are calling .json() on the response. If the endpoint didn't return JSON, this line will error. Take it out to remove the error.
